# Printing Names In Batch

Tags: batch-file

im creating a game (hacking simulator) and i cant figure out how to set and print a variable (name) please help

```
ECHO Type Your PC Name

set /P %name%=



goto main


cls

color 02

ECHO Working

timeout /t 1 /nobreak

ECHO ...

timeout /t 1 /nobreak

ECHO ...

ECHO ip adress: 195.546.32.462

ECHO PC's connected: "youtubePC" "%name%"

set /p input=Command:

if %input%==main goto main

goto error
```

Answer (score 3):

You need

```
set /P name=
```

`%name%` means the **contents** of `name`